# How do i focus a input type="text" when my id changes in page url?

Tags: javascript, input, focus

How do i focus a input type="text" automatic when my id changes in page url ?

For example: http://mysite.php?id=2
I want to focus the mouse on my type="text" when my PHP IF statement is met without using buttons.

```
<form>
<input type="text">
</form>
```

It should go something like: php IF (condition) { focus the mouse to input type="text" based on id of url }

Comment: to print code, select the text and ctrl+k, I actually edited your post but you messed it up again, I'll let you fix this.

Comment: The mouse doesn't have focus, the keyboard does.  Retagged to javascript, this seems to have nothing to do with Java.

Answer (score 1):

You mean this:

```
<?php
  if (intval($_GET['id']) === 1) // adjust value
  {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // focus element
  var el = document.getElementById('elem_id');
  el.focus();
</script>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I know many ways to do this as you have done it. This solution is good but it ain't practical.
I have as many type="text" inputs as there are ids. That means that each input has the same id name (elem_id) as the id number grows. I need to give each input type="text" its number that is the same as id number of url.

input type="text" id="elem_id(some code that tells that the number is the same as $_GET['id'])"

Comment: @cincg: The problem is that you are using same id for multiple elements. An id should be used once per element per document.

Comment: Well yes, that is the problem that needs to be solved. You surely don't suggest that i write this code for each id if there are 3000 ids. That would mean also that i would need to create 3000 inputs and give each its id name also.